# I need help to properly solve the result for getting the attackspeed

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ats
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double baseats;
        int bonusats;
        int level;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter base attackspeed: ");
        baseats = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter bonus attack speed %: ");
        bonusats = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the level: ");
        level = sc.nextInt();
        double as = baseats * (1 + (bonusats / 100) * (level - 1));
        
        System.out.printf("The character's current attack speed is: %.3f", as);
    }
}
```

This is my code so far and when it calculates it brings me the same result as the entered base attack speed.
[this should be the result of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5MWL.png)

Comment: Use a debugger and check the values of your variables. If you don't have a debugger or don't know how to use one, add `System.out.println` statements to the print the values of your variables.

Comment: `bonusats / 100` is Integer division  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0